# Xcode: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver'

Tags: macos, sonarqube, classpath, h2, sonar-runner

I'm using sonar-runner 2.4 with JDK 1.8 to build a sonar report on OSX.
It fails with the error `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver'`

Here's the full stack trace:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_60 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /...../External/Sonar/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: /...../External/Sonar/sonar-runner/bin/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
21:43:38.350 INFO  - Load global repositories
21:43:39.809 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=1459ms
21:43:39.810 INFO  - Server id: 20150902220143
21:43:39.811 INFO  - User cache: /Users/...../.sonar/cache
21:43:39.818 INFO  - Install plugins
21:43:40.541 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
21:43:41.034 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.062s
Final Memory: 11M/245M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:81)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:103)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:72)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 36 more
```

It somehow looks like I need to [install H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/build.html), but I have not been able to find out how and trial and error did not succeed.

Comment: On what DB is your SQ 5.1 running? Looks like you have forgot to specified the DB properties, and so SonarQube Runner defaults to H2.

Comment: No, I have all the configuration set as in Jenkins, it's working fine there. In the log above the project configuration has been in the wrong directory - fixed that, but the error stays the same.